# Horizontal and vertical scroll are funky in Safari

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a div that both scrolls horizontally and vertically. It's working perfectly in Chrome but Safari seems to block vertical scroll for a few moments, after a horizontal scroll. I'm using react-swipeable-views component, however I dont think that this is a components issue. (In this video Im trying to scroll immediately after horizontal one and it only allows me after a second of not touching anything). Overflow is set to auto.

[image: example]

```js
slideRenderer = params => {
    const { index, key } = params;

    if (this.state.timetable === null) return;

    let phase = index % 7 < 0 ? 7 + (index % 7) : index % 7;
    let day = dayOfWeek[d.getDay()] + phase;
    day = day % 7;

    let week =
      (parseInt(this.state.currentWeek) +
        Math.abs(Math.floor((dayOfWeek[d.getDay()] + index) / 7))) %
      4;
    let lessons = [];
    if (this.state.timetable[week][day] === undefined)
      lessons.push(
        <div
          key={key * index}
          style={{
            display: "flex",
            flexDirection: "column",
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
            width: "100%",
            height: "70vh"
          }}
        >
          <h1>Пар нет :)</h1>
        </div>
      );
    else {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.state.timetable[week][day].lessons.length; i++) {
        lessons.push(
          <Lesson
            key={index * key + i}
            lesson={this.state.timetable[week][day].lessons[i]}
          />
        );
      }
    }
    return (
      <div key={key} style={Object.assign({}, styles.slide)}>
        {lessons}
      </div>
    );
  };

  handleChangeIndex = index => {
    this.setState({index});
  };

render() {
    return (
      <div className="Timetable tab">
          <VirtualizeSwipeableViews
              overscanSlideBefore={2}
              ignoreNativeScroll={true}
              index={this.state.index}
              onChangeIndex={this.handleChangeIndex}
              containerStyle={{ maxHeight: "83vh" }}
             slideRenderer={this.slideRenderer}/>
      </div>
    )}
```

Comment: give some code for it??

Comment: @nikhilsugandh my fault, edited

Comment: @nikhilsugandh OP provided code, were you planning on helping?